# Website Architecture Rethink

Tags: html, architecture

I will try and be succinct and you can ask for further information if you feel it would help.

We have designed and built a website for delivering training courses. We are continuing to add Courses and Lessons. Our design approach has been to design the Lessons in a similar way to designing a book in that each Lesson contains many 'pages' with no scrolling, of a fixed size, and the text and images carefully laid out individually with attention to the flow of the content and the use of white space. A navigation bar at the bottom allows the user to go to the next or previous 'page', jump to any of the sub-sections of the Lesson or jump to a specific 'page'.

We have created hundreds of Lessons and each Lesson has been approximately 20 'pages' in length. Our simple but effective approach has been to have a single html file for each Lesson and create each 'page' within its own Div. The visibility of the Divs are controlled by JavaScript functions called by the navigation bar at the bottom of the window (swf file). This way when managing and laying out all of the content we don't have thousands of individual html files and navigating a Lesson is simple. Also we can easily open up a complete Lesson and review it in isolation in a browser.

Just to complete the picture we have developed Course html files which act as a wrapper to pull in and display collections of Lessons. The Lessons are displayed within an iFrame in the Course html file and xml files are used to determine which Lessons a Course contains.

The project has been very successful (here comes the 'but') but our client is now increasing the length of new Lessons and it is this which is forcing us to re-consider our approach. Our client has a very managed corporate intranet and all Users have IE8. When viewing a Course and clicking to view a Lesson the whole Lesson has to be downloaded just to view the first 'page' (you knew that of course!). It was slow but acceptable before, now it is becoming a real problem.

So, eventually, here is the question: how could we evolve our approach to delivering our content more efficiently, asking the server to deliver page by page rather than a whole Lesson up front?

When the project started we were told by our client hosting the website that we could not create a dynamic website accessing SQL or similar so we went static with xml data. We have more freedom now and could employ a more dynamic approach. However I would prefer not to start again as we have a huge amount of legacy content. An ideal would be to evolve our current approach but to manage the downloading better.

I look forward to hearing your thoughts.

Regards

Chris

Answer (score 0):

So you have some javascript like

```
openPage(pageId);
```

That takes a div id, hides the current "page" and opens the new one. You probably have a collection of those "pageIds" somewhere that provides the inter-page navigation (or you could be building it dynamically from the div ID's, but that would be tricky, distinguishing "page" div ids from normal div ids, so I'm sticking with my first assertion, you are keeping a list of ids.

I'd suggest adding a url to each id, and having the javascript check the iFrame's location against the requested pageId, and if it's different, load the new html file.   It could default to "current location" so you don't have to modify all the existing content, just the javascript.

This would allow you to put the first page in a different html file then all the others, and to shred them into appropriately sized files.

If you are clever, you will kick off a process after you load the first page to go ahead and start pulling the other pages for the lesson into the browser cache so that they are quick to display once the user is done with the first page.